# What does '*' mean in the output to 'history' command?

Tags: command-line, bash, history

I was seeing my `history` when I found a line with a `*`

[image: History has a command with *]

whereas, in general, the `history` has an output  without any `*`

[image: Normal history output]

I noticed this for the first time. When does this `*` appear and why?

**EDIT:**

Surprisingly the `*` dissapears after some time!

[image: Star disappears in history]

Can someone tell why there was a `*` in the first place and the logic behind it disappearing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [`bash(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/bash.1.html)

> **history [n]**
>
> With no options, display the  command  history  list  with  line
>   numbers.  Lines listed with a * have been modified.